# Aptana 3 doesn't recognize <?php ... ?>

Tags: php, aptana

I'm just started using Aptana (coming from Dreamweaver). I've imported my old html files that use css and php.
Every time I use `<?php echo php_variable_here ?>` Aptana marks it as an error saying `"<" missing '>'`

Example of my php use: `<?php echo $share_button ?>`

What am I doing wrong? If nothing else works maybe I'll just disable php error verification (how can I do that?)

Comment: what abt if u use only echo php_variable_here  without php tags , is it running, let me now then

Comment: tell me about ur operating system. if you are using windows means you have to update aptana based on php

Comment: do you have PDT installed in aptana?

Comment: I do if PDT shipped with their default installer, which I guess it is because on the About I see the logo of PHP (Aptana PHP Editor). @Suresh I'm using Win7, why update Aptana if I just downloaded it from their website?

Comment: Have you change perspective to web perspective?

Comment: Yes it's the default perspective (Web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the file extension must be .php in order to Aptana recognize the  code.

Comment: You should look at the preferences. I don't use Aptana, but I assume, that there you can define which content-type is associated with which file extension. btw: Always answer your own questions and accept this is not what SO was meant to be ;)

Comment: I know, but when no one answers my questions and I find out the solution... unanswered questions aren't useful, this way someone else may find it useful ;) you can also vote to close

Comment: By the way, +1 for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I've found - and I can't say I understand *why* this it's this way, but it seems aptana keeps track of what type a file *was* when it was created, regardless of what it is now. I had the same problem. I had a php tag that it was not recognizing in an html file, I changed the extension, still didn't work. Then I copied the contents of the file to a safe spot, and created a new file within aptana with the php extension, pasted the same code, and it recognized.